# Why can you not create an Infinite Battery?

Tags: batteries, electron

As far I know the power electricity is flow of electrons from anode to cathode of the battery. So basically the electrons flow through the circuit and return to cathode. Why can't we reuse these returned electrons to create an infinite battery ?

Comment: Because the electrons come from redox reactions, and the chemicals eventually deplete.

Comment: Or more descriptively, migrate from one side to the other.  You'd have move those ions back on the starting side... ie, recharge the battery, if it's a chemistry/structure/enclosure that can tolerate that.

Comment: You will need some sort of energy source. Like mechanical energy, but then it's a generator, or thermal energy,  e.g. Peltier effect. Or light, e.g. solar panel. However the closest to the concept would be fuel cell, e.g. if you can supply the consumable into the battery and remove the waste continuously, it will operate infinitely indefinitely.

Comment: All energy is converted from something. Mass is the most efficient  source and even nuclear reactors are only 50% efficient until spent.

Comment: Electrons flow from cathode to anode. If you drop a brick from the roof of a house, it converts potential energy into kinetic energy and does work when it hits the floor. To repeat the test you must carry that brick to the roof again and, in doing so you put back energy into the brick. Please don't talk about infinite batteries.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is energy. Actually, for almost any physics problem, the answer is 'track the energy'.

In a battery, it's the potential energy of the chemicals, their ability to do work by changing to other chemicals with a different electronic arrangement and lower energy, that provides the energy to push charge round an external circuit. Once all the high potential energy chemicals have turned into low energy ones, no more work can be done.

If you want to keep pushing electrons round the circuit, re-use the charge that returns (so to speak), then you have to keep supplying energy. You could supply mechanical energy to a generator, thermal energy to a Peltier module, or chemical energy in the form of oxygen and a fuel to a fuel cell. These will all make 'infinite batteries' according to your definition, and the last *is* a chemical battery.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is, chemistry. Those electrons don't go back to where they came from, they go to a different part of the battery, essentially. All the electrons that leave the battery are the product of a chemical reaction, and once the reagents are used up and the reaction's run to completion, you can't get any more out.

Chemical reactions of the reduction/oxidation (or 'redox') variety always involve the transfer of electrons. It's just that in this case, the battery's construction forces the electrons to take the long way around.

Comment: Strangely enough, while the short name of the reaction is "redox", the full name is "oxidation-reduction". Bonkers, I know.

Comment: Well, I guess oxred just sounded too weird.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
Energy has to drive the flow of electrons in the first place. A different kind of energy, like chemical energy. Chemical energy is what pushes the electrons, imparting energy into the flow of electrons.  That energy gets used up when we power something.  The electrons flow back to the battery but the energy doesnt. The battery has a finite supply of energy in it stored in chemical form.

Comment: Does the amount of energy usage depend on the load ? In other words, if I just short anode to cathode will the flow of electrons remain for longer time ? Is there an equation for how long the battery will last based on the load ?

Comment: The battery has a finite amount of energy. Power is the rate at which energy is used; higher power means same energy in less time.  Power is $P = V^2/R$, where $V$ is the battery voltage and $R$ is the resistance (load) you put between the terminals.  If you short the terminals together that resistance will be near 0.  That means power will be very high, and you will drain the batter very quickly.  All that energy coming out at once is why batteries get hot and sometimes explode.

Answer (score -2):

All reaction in life generates heat, the heat is the result of used up energy correct? When electric charge runs though a wire a small amount of heat is being released this is because everything on earth has a small amount of resistance so even though electricity travels through conducting objects it still has to fight resistance that the object obtains.

That process generates heat which is energy lose.  So when electricity travels out of a battery and through a conducting object small electric signals (heat) is being released into the air.  This process essentially drains the battery. So basically you can't have an infinite battery unless you have some form of retaining the energy lost and reusing it.

This is my *theory*  in a nutshell. If you want me to elaborate on your question please let me know.

Comment: Why the down votes

Comment: Heat is not "small electric signals", and while energy loss is why the battery is eventually drained, this is not answering the question. The question is not the sort that can be answered by just going to conservation of energy--the person clearly understands that their concept goes against conservation of energy and they want to understand what they have wrong. At least, that's my view of it.

Comment: This doesn't describe the *mechanism*, but it's essentially accurate as thermodynamics is your basic "details don't matter, this is the inevitable result" legitimate way of debunking any proposed perpetual device.

Comment: I might be optimistic about the asker's knowledge, but this question sounded to me more like "my understanding suggests that this impossible situation might be possible. Obviously it isn't, but why isn't it?".

Comment: This is your "theory"? Huh?

Comment: I meant to say electric charge and heat. If you think about tho heat is just atoms vibrating. And all adams hold electric charge.

Comment: @uint128_t Yes this is my theory. I took 10th Biology this year and I learned that all cellular reaction results in the form of heat, which is energy lost. Thank you for complimenting on my answer tho

Comment: I guess you are not aware of superconductors? Current can run in superconductors forever, and that's how strong magnets are made since a while ago.

Comment: Yes but those magnets lose the magnetism.(energy being used up) The earth core is the worlds magnet and its slowly losing its magnetism right?

Comment: No pun intended

Comment: Here read this https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/179374/is-current-in-superconductors-infinite-if-they-have-0-resistance-then-i-v-r-s

Comment: @GovaDEster, 'all cellular reaction results in the form of heat' - fireflies

Comment: @Chu formally known as respiration

Comment: The heat is energy being lost and that drains the battery